# Using a form as the windows desktop background

Tags: .net, desktop

I have written a program that is a screen saver containing a 3D Engine rendering to a picture box (set to the size of the form, which is set to the size of the screen). But as nice as it is as a screen saver, I would like to adapt the program so instead of being a screen saver, the form would be placed behind the desktop icons, but in front of the wallpaper?

I have seen a similar program that existed on mac that rendered a 3D rotating earth, but I haven't found anything similar for Windows.

Comment: I don't think there is any such place as "behind the desktop icons but in front of the wallpaper" on Windows. Might need a cunning plan.

Comment: I imagine it would need a very cunning plan, but I have seen that VLC media player is capable of rendering to the background, so I would have thought that something similar could be achieved

Comment: Indeed? Well VLC is open source, so may be worth seeing how it's done... intrigued now.

Answer (score 0):

I would break this into two parts.

Part 1: A Program that takes configuration setting from a file to create a rendered image to use as a wallpaper background at regular intervals.

Part 2: A small winforms app to alter the configuration for the program in Part 1.

Comment: I did have a similar thought, but the update would have to be very regular, possibly too regular for that